# How can I create a checkbox to select and then display week day wise progress comparison in Google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I need to know how to show week day wise progress comparison between different weeks in a Google sheet. So far, I have been able to show comparisons for a single day from each week but I am looking to get multiple week days (for example: week 10 should have day 1, day 2, day3 etc., week 11 should have day 1, day 2, day 3 etc. until day 7)

I am attaching a link to view the file for your convenience. What it is showing now is single day comparison but I would like it to display multiple days from each week.

[googlesheet]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GNru6Kl0MEQFjJ5yTfYIyrMVw_Rp9vz-nSy6FAwShgw/edit#gid=1666606207

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you are trying to do and how are you currently doing it? Also, the spreadsheet shared has the access blocked, please create a public sheet with the access to anyone with the link.

Comment: access denied to your spreadsheet!

Comment: View access given. Please keep me posted

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GNru6Kl0MEQFjJ5yTfYIyrMVw_Rp9vz-nSy6FAwShgw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: ok thx, but too complex. You should provide a minima reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You can check from B92 (Weekday wise progress comparison). That is where i need to use multiple days from each week. There is a yellow bar (B91) where you can select week day 1, week day 2 until 7 but What i need is a checkbox where i can select day 1, 2, 3, 4 until 7 from week 10, day 1, 2, 3 etc.. from week 11 to compare weekday wise progress

Comment: Hello, the sheet shared still has the access denied, can you share it publicly?

Comment: The issue has been resolved. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Can you share the solution as an answer so more people can benefit from it?

Comment: @Kessy, I have used sumifs, vlookup functions in Google sheet, created a field to select the days of the week for the desired result from data > data validation > list of items